Does a set with no divisibility pairs necessarily have arbitrarily large gaps?
The set of prime numbers has the following properties:

No element is divisible by any other element.
We can find arbitrarily large gaps between consecutive elements.

Does (1) imply (2) for arbitrary sets of natural numbers?
The standard argument for prime gaps (that $n!+2$ through $n!+n$ are composite) seems to rely on a property of primality that's stronger than (1).

I just noticed that you need to include some prerequisite axiom that 0. The set is infinite.  Or put "Does (1) imply (2) for .... infinite, arbitrary sets of nats."
